# How to map an auto increment field in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, xml, hibernate, netbeans

Please have a look at the below XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<!-- Generated Feb 17, 2015 10:01:43 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1 -->
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.main.Family" table="family" catalog="****" optimistic-lock="version">
        <id name="idFamily" type="int">
            <column name="idFamily" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <many-to-one name="employee" class="model.main.Employee" fetch="select">
            <column name="idEmployee" not-null="true" />
        </many-to-one>
        <property name="firstName" type="string">
            <column name="FirstName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="middleName" type="string">
            <column name="MiddleName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastName" type="string">
            <column name="LastName" length="45" />
        </property>
        <property name="dob" type="date">
            <column name="DOB" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="passportNumber" type="string">
            <column name="PassportNumber" length="45" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="dateLeft" type="date">
            <column name="DateLeft" length="10" />
        </property>
        <property name="lastUpdated" type="timestamp">
            <column name="LastUpdated" length="19" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="visas" table="visa" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key>
                <column name="idFamily" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="model.main.Visa" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

It is the `Hibernate` mapping class of my database table `Family`. We create the database separately using MySQL Work bench and then generate the mapping classes. We auto generated the mapping files using netbeans as mentioned in ***"Generating Hibernate Mapping Files and Java Classes"*** section of [netbeans tutorial](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/hibernate-webapp.html).

Now we have a problem. That is, we changed the `primary key` (`idFamily`) of our table `Family` to an `auto generated` field inside MySQL. Now, how can we change the above hibernate code so it identifies the `idFamily` as an auto generated one?

The other question is, manually editing one mapping class without regenerating all the mappings via a tool can "break" the system? For an example, like messing up with relationships?

Comment: Why don't you regenerate the files for hibernate and compare the differences?

Answer (score 6):

In Annotation It work for me as

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
```

for you hope it works

```
<generated-value strategy="IDENTITY" />
```

Comment: Nice one. I got bogged by `Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'blablabla' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.` This one solved it for me :-)

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for an *identity* column. That indicates that the column value is auto-generated as an identity for the row by the RDBMS.

<generator class="identity" />

See the these [Hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id) for more information. According to it:

> Identity
>   supports identity columns in DB2, MySQL, MS SQL Server, Sybase and HypersonicSQL. The returned identifier is of type long, short or int.

Answer (score 3):

Just replace your generator class to increment it will treat it as autoincrement

```
<generator class="increment"/>
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use Hibernate to create the id; he wants to tell Hibernate that it's already been auto-generated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.tech.spring4.model.User" table="Customer">
<id name="id" type="long">
 <column name="USERID"  unique="true"/>
             <generator class="increment"/>
</id>
<property name="username"><column name="username" length="30" not-null="true"></column></property>
<property name="email"><column name="email" length="100" not-null="true"></column></property>
<property name="address"><column name="address" length="100" not-null="true"></column></property>
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```